# Simple variable check returns false, should be true

Tags: javascript, node.js

A little background.

I am receiving a message from my server that comes in the form of `<Buffer 00 00 00>`   I using the Node string_decoder function to turn this into a utf8 encoded string:

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

global.message = null;

 client.on('data', function(chunk) {
   console.log(`New Message ${decoder.write(chunk)}`);
   message = decoder.write(chunk);
 })
```

When running, this logs out `New Message OK` which is correct

In another function, I am then looping until the global variable is equal to OK, however I am running into some problems:

```
console.log(`Global vari ${message}`);
if(message != "OK"){
    setTimeout(check, 1000);
} else {
    return cb(true);
}
```

The above logs out `Global vari OK` however the if statement fails.  I have done a typeof check on message, and it outputs string as expected.

I'm stumped as to what is going on here, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Have you tried with `.trim()`? `"OK" != "OK "`

Comment: Console statements are tricky and may not be outputting in the order of your code. Try logging in the `else` statement.

Comment: maybe try this to make sure everything matches .tostring().toupper().trim()

Answer (score 1):

Try to trim before comparaison to make sure there no extra spaces :

```
if(sanitized.trim() != "OK"){
    setTimeout(check, 1000);
} else {
    return cb(true);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't contain any BOM character or any other invisible data that makes it not equal to OK?

You can try removing everything but the letters, like:

```
let sanitized = message.replace(/\W/g, '');
console.log(`Global vari ${sanitized}`);
if(sanitized != "OK"){
    setTimeout(check, 1000);
} else {
    return cb(true);
}
```

and see what it prints now.

You can see these answers about BOM characters and the problems they cause:

- [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom/38038099#38038099)
- [JSON Specification and usage of BOM/charset-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990095/json-specification-and-usage-of-bom-charset-encoding/38036753#38036753)