# python unable to load a json file with utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, json, urllib2

With the following python code:

```
filePath = urllib2.urlopen('xx.json')
fileJSON = json.loads(filePath.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Where the xx.json looks like:

```
{
    "tags": [{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "Airport",
        "name_en": "Airport",
        "name_cn": "机场",
        "display": false
    }]
}
```

I see the following exception:

```
fileJSON = json.loads(filePath.read().decode('utf-8'))
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The code works before the Chinese characters are added to the json file, when I also added the .decode('utf-8') behind the read() as well.

I am not sure what needs to be done?

Comment: That all seems to work just fine for me (Python 2.7.5).

Comment: Odd. `urllib2.urlopen('xxx.json')` raises `ValueError: unknown url type: xxx.json` for me. `'file:xxx.json'` works for me.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Guess: your *actual* code has lines between `urlopen()` and `json.loads()`. In particular, you've already `.read()` the contents of the file and this `.read()` is returning an empty string.

Comment: 2nd guess. Your `xxx.json` file is encoded with a BOM. Can you run  `file xxx.json` and show us the result?

Comment: This is yet another case that Python 3 handles better (clearer errors when it fails, and better defaults so it doesn't fail).

Comment: I updated the file with the real file that I was using. The two lines are consecutive i.e. the streams are not read in between the two lines I had.

Comment: @Robᵩ I updated to a real file, could you please check again?

Comment: @larsks I updated the file to the one that I actually run into problem with. Could you please check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/wherego-sims/tags.json 
$ file tags.json 
tags.json: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

This file begins with a byte order mark (EF BB BF), which is illegal in JSON ([JSON Specification and usage of BOM/charset-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990095/json-specification-and-usage-of-bom-charset-encoding)). You must first decode this using `'utf-8-sig'` in Python to get a valid JSON unicode string.

```
json.loads(filePath.read().decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

For what it's worth, Python 3 (which you should be using) will give a specific error in this case and guide you in handling this malformed file:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Namely, by specifying that you wish to discard the BOM if it exists (again, it's not conventional to use this in UTF-8, particularly with JSON which is always encoded in UTF-8 so it is worse than useless):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.load(open('tags.json', encoding='utf-8-sig'))
```

Comment: Good digging. I was beginning to suspect something along those lines