# JSON Simple unexpected character?

Tags: java, c#, json

```
Unexpected character () at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
    at net.ddns.coolpvp.Testing.main(Testing.java:22)
```

I was making a TCP Server on Java, it was receiving a json and it gave this error, but I checked and the first character is '{', how can I fix this? I have no clue. I would be very grateful if you could help me
EDIT: The JSON is generated by .NET Framework in a C# Application and this is a JSON

```
{"Type":"level-info","LevelNumber":1}
```

This is how the C# Application is generating the JSON
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace Testing
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("localhost", 152);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };
            writer.WriteLine(new RequestLevelInfo(1).ToJSONString());
            client.Close();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

RequestLevelInfo.cs

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Testing
{
    public class RequestLevelInfo
    {
        public string Type { get { return "level-info"; } }
        public int LevelNumber { get; }
        public RequestLevelInfo(int level)
        {
            LevelNumber = level;
        }
        public string ToJSONString()
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The Server is reading it using a BufferedReader using the readLine method

```
package testing;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
            server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 152));
            Socket client = server.accept();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String dataReceived = reader.readLine();
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(dataReceived);
            System.out.println(json.toJSONString());
            client.close();
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your JSON in your question?

Comment: How is the JSON content generated and sent to the server? How does the server read it? Please include the code in the question

Comment: Please also show us your JSON file so that we can see if the error is due to the JSON file.

Comment: Did you use something like .writeUTF(String), because this method prepends two bytes as length at the beginning, like [0x00][0x01][a]?

Comment: So as far as I can see the error is not due to the JSON file, could you also show us the code with which you read the JSON file?

Comment: Let me think about it...

Comment: Are you using the same encoding on both ends?  It looks like the writer is using Unicode (a.k.a. UTF-16),  but the `InputStreamReader` does not specify.  I would use UTF-8 on both ends if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your C# code: it's sending incorrect JSON.

You are using the `Encoding.UTF8` object. This object includes an invisible and unnecessary "byte order marker" character, which the Java JSON parser does not understand. JSON "must not" use a byte order mark character: [JSON Specification and usage of BOM/charset-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990095/json-specification-and-usage-of-bom-charset-encoding)

The solution is to create your own instance of `UTF8Encoding`. For example:

```
UTF8Encoding jsonEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), jsonEncoding) { AutoFlush = true };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hello**, I thought about your code and changed something, here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.json"));
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(bufferedReader);
        System.out.println(data.get("Type"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

> This is the content of the test.json File:
> `{"Type":"level-info","LevelNumber":1}`
>
> My output is: `level-info`

Please check if you really have `org.json.simple.JSONObject`, `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` and `org.json.simple.parser.ParseException` imported.
Not that you accidentally imported anything else.

Have fun, I hope I could help you!

> EDIT

So, for me the error occurred with the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String string = "{name=Asel, number1=40.34, number2=29.343}";
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(string);
        System.out.println(object.get("name"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But not with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String string = "{\"name\":\"Asel\", \"number1\":\"40.34\", \"number2\":\"29.343\"}";
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(string);
        System.out.println(object.get("name"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Therefore I wonder if your string that you really get from your TCP socket is exactly `{"Type":"level-info","LevelNumber":"1"}` and not something wrong liek this: `{"Type"="level-info","LevelNumber"="1"}`

To test it you could try to replace `=` with `:` in the string of TPC Socket and see if the error still occurs.

> JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(dataReceived.replace(*"="*, *":"*));

Comment: So, that's basically what I did, but I was reading from a file, I was actually reading from a BufferedReader that was reading from an InputStreamReader that was reading from a TCP Socket, so I can't actually do that

Comment: Ok, wait a second

Comment: I edited my answer, but unfortunately I can't test it with a socket connection right now, but I can also do it from the file readen with a buffered reader.

Comment: I don't think parsing from the reader is good for me, because in this server I have to read a couple more times, can you look at the entire code that I posted now to see if there's any mistake? Or something that I am missing on? Thank you for the attention

Comment: Yes I can wait a second

Comment: What do you get when you print "client.getInputStream().toString" in the console?

Comment: can you please send the code from Testing.java class line 22?

Comment: The Line 22 is 'JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(dataReceived);' and when I print that I get 'java.net.SocketInputStream@75b84c92'

Comment: Ok, I just got the same error and am trying to fix it, then I will send you my answer :D

Comment: Take a look at my answer below "EDIT" :D

Comment: I already tested what it receives and it actually receives the correct JSON, but if you want to get the same exact error that I got just copy paste the code and try to change it, I am in this problem for 3 hours now, I have tried everything since checking the received data to completly changing how I read it and nothing has worked

Comment: I am sorry, but unfortunately I don't know what to do next, but I would still be happy about a positive rating. But if you really want, I can try to run your entire code on my PC tomorrow and try to fix it again?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give you a positive rating because you really tried to help, if you could run my entire code that would be great. Thank you for taking time to try to help me

Comment: Ok thanks for your upvote or whatever, I'll try again tomorrow