# pandas read_json returns ValueError: Expected object or value

Tags: python, json, pandas, toad, file-encodings

Using pandas:1.4.2, I have file.json file with content as list

```
[
  {
    "col1":"v1",
    "col2":"v2"
  },
  ...
  {
    "col1":"v3",
    "col2":"v4"
  }
]
```

Read file as

```
pd.read_json('file.json', orient='records')
```

Gives **ValueError: Expected object or value**

I produced the file using Toad export wizard with default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Toad default exports json as UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM)

There should be no BOM in json [4990095](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990095/json-specification-and-usage-of-bom-charset-encoding).

To resolve re-save file as UTF-8, and next time using Toad check 'no BOM' option.

Comment: More information about BOM in error message could save time finding the cause.